# Get pictures from video and glue them into another video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the dimensions and coordinates of some areas on the video that need to be cut and glued into another video.

I do it now with two commands.

first I save the pictures:

ffmpeg -y -i INPUT -filter_complex "[0:0]crop=704:396:500:500,scale=1920:-1[mvid0];[0:0]crop=708:398:502:502,scale=1920:-1[mvid1];[0:0]crop=711:399:505:505,scale=1920:-1[mvid2];[0:0]crop=715:402:508:508,scale=1920:-1[mvid3]"  -map "[mvid0"] "000000.png" -map "[mvid1"] "000001.png" -map "[mvid2"] "000002.png" -map "[mvid3"] "000003.png" 
(gives an error but saves pictures),

second, concat pictures into the video:

ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

Can i do this with one command?

Comment: What are the commands?

Comment: Add commands. Changed the question

Comment: So, you want a MP4 which has 4 frames only?

Comment: For example - yes. I don't want to put the whole command here. It's too big.